# Debugging a website on iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, angular, debugging, safari, load

I have a website that loads perfectly on various browsers on Windows Laptop, Android and Fire OS. The same site refuses to load on a Safari on an iPhone.

It is an angular application. While I see the index.html load, the angular does not load. I need to debug to figure out what is happening. I only have a Windows 10 laptop. How can I debug the website running on Safari on an iPhone from my Windows 10 laptop?

Comment: Are you sure it loads on Internet Explorer? Generally it doesn't load. So you need to require to  "import 'core-js/es7/array' " to polyfills.ts It might solve your problem on Safari or iPhone

Comment: Yup. And you ask this because?

Comment: Are all of these in your poliffill.ts:

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import "core-js/client/shim"; 
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a windows laptop, you will need an online service like browserstack. There is no way around this. Physical Iphones can only be debugged with Safari, running on physical Mac desktops or laptops. Browserstack is a subscription service, but it will be a lot cheaper than buying the hardware. (No affiliation)

Answer (score -1):

Follow below link

Building and debugging websites and web applications for mobile devices can be a hassle. On the desktop we have powerful debugging tools; most browsers have a web inspector of some kind. But we don’t have those tools for devices like the iPhone and iPad … that is, until now!

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: Yeah, this link doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ShilpaNagavara what then you want to do? I would've provided the same link for the problems w/ Safari. So maybe we don't understand the problem you have w/ it?

Comment: @Pawel, The link above details debugging procedure on a Mac machine. As I have said in my original post, I only have a Windows 10 machine. I need to know if there is a way to debug a website loaded on Safari on an iPhone using a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Please describe how to do it right here. The Tutsplus website can become unavailable, and we don't want to depend on that.